# PowerShell: Run batch file and write output to text file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file in my PowerShell script that I want to run and write its output to a text file. I tried the following:

```
Start-Process C:\path\file.bat | Out-File C:\path\output.txt
```

I also tried using [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Tee-Object) and [Write-Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output?view=powershell-5.1) in place of [Out-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Out-File), but nothing is being written to the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Start-Transcript?view=powershell-5.0) and [`Stop-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Stop-Transcript?view=powershell-5.0) to let the PowerShell console write all console output to a text file.

Use it like this:

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\temp\log.txt
&C:\path\file.bat
Stop-Transcript
```

See [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a flag I can use so that the batch file output is not displayed in the Powershell window?

Comment: @StewC hmm, it may be possible to wrap the three commands into a single method, and than pipe it's output to `Out-Null`. Something like `Invoke-BatchFile | Out-Null`.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but when I tried it the transcript only included the commands I entered (i.e. the path of the bat file) but not stdout nor stderr from the actual bat file. The output from the bat file did appear on screen but not the log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output of the bat file, e.g. results of a build script, then I found the following worked best:

```
$Product = 'ProductName' 
&C:\Path\$Product.bat | Out-File C:\Path\$Product-Output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed a couple more parameters:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Path\File.bat' -RedirectStandardOutput 'C:\Path\Output.txt' -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
```

`-RedirectStandardOutput` to send output to your text file, `-Wait` to wait for the batch file to complete and `-WindowStyle Hidden` to hide the window used for the batch file.